# Can't export default from .d.ts file

Tags: typescript, import, sass

I try to use scss as module so I created `declaration.d.ts`:

```
declare module '*.scss' {
    const styles: {[key: string]: string};
    export default styles;
}
```

The IDE tells me `A default export can only be used in an ECMAScript-style module`
and doesn't suggest me scss file in import. Of course, nothing is built. TypeScript (TS) can't find the `./x.scss` file. 
The project is using Babel as compiler and TS is used for typechecking only.